# How does an application override other applications' zoom button?

Tags: macos, hook, zooming

Mac applications like [Moom](http://manytricks.com/moom/) and [RightZoom](http://www.blazingtools.com/downloads.html#RightZoom) seem to override the default behavior of the green maximize button on windows that belong to other applications. How would an application hook itself in to be triggered by the zoom button on windows system-wide?

Comment: Hey Daniel! Have you figured out how they do it?

Comment: sadly no, I have not.